# How to add a continuation for cancelled tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have the following code

```
try
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
    {                   
        Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop the task");
    Console.ReadLine();
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Got an exception => {e.InnerExceptions[0].Message}");
}
```

In this when I cancel the task it always throws the error and the continuation task is not being executed.

But when I remove `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled` from the **continueWith** parameter then the continuation task is being executed.

The book I am following has the code with the parameter  `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled`.

Is the behaviour correct or what is wrong here ?

I am new to threading. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first task isn't actually being cancelled - you're observing that cancellation has been requested, but then you're letting the first task complete normally... which means your "only on cancellation" task is cancelled. If you change your code to:

```
while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
{
    Console.Write("*");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

... then it will behave as you expected.

Comment: Yes perfect !! it works fine. I will accept the answer shortly since its saying me to do after 7 mins.

Thanks !!!

Comment: @shansfk: Do you understand *why* you need that? Let me know if it's not clear - the understanding part is more important than the code change :)

Comment: Jon please explain. I couldn't grasp the reason still. Thanks.

Comment: @shansfk: Okay - in your original code, the status of the first task will end up as `RanToCompletion` - because although you notice that the cancellation token was cancelled, the method just completed as normal. Whereas with my code, the method throws a `TaskCanceledException`, which is what sets the state to `Canceled` - which is what then triggers the continuation to run.

Comment: Got it. Understood the reason now. :)